Why my spring boot app not generate table
Hello Why doesn't the defined syntax, including the Java entity class 'Application' annotated with necessary JPA annotations, and the specified database configuration in the 'application.properties' file, successfully create the corresponding table in the PostgreSQL database specified by the JDBC URL?
MainCLass.java
@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"main.java.com.ishotit.api.v1.model"})
@EnableConfigurationProperties(RabbitMqConfig.class)
public class ApiApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

Model:
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Application {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "clientId", nullable = false)
    private String clientId;

    @Column(name = "url", nullable = false)
    private String url;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "hostname", nullable = false)
    private String hostname;

    @Column(name = "cssurl", nullable = true)
    private String cssurl;

}

application.properties:
# DataSource settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ishotit
spring.datasource.username=ishotit
spring.datasource.password=apipassword

# JPA/Hibernate settings
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

# Debug SQL and Hibernate types
# logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
# logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE

# RabbitMQ settings
rabbitmq.username=guest
rabbitmq.password=guest
rabbitmq.host=localhost
rabbitmq.port=5672
rabbitmq.queueFile=queueFile
rabbitmq.topic=topic


You Lost to adding @Table(<table_name>) top of your entity.

@MortezaJalambadani Table annotation is only needed if the name of the table differs from the entity class name.

One of the reasons could be the package structure. By default the entity class will only be found if it is in the same package as the main application class (or a sub-package of it). Otherwise you need to add the @EnityScan annotation to the main application class.

i have add my main class

Yes. Please also add the the packages  in use. Are you sure the package name starts with main.java?
